# How to add the mac address of the android phone to allowed device list of WiFi hotspot using android programming?

Tags: android, macos, wifi, tethering

How to add the mac address of the android phone to allowed device list of WiFi hotspot(add phone's mac address to allowed devices list). I mean, my app installed two android devices, I set my WiFi Hotspot security type "Open". The other device connect my WiFi Hotspot and I saw it's mac address (I have a method which name is getClients(), it returns mac addresses of devices that connect my WiFi hotspot). When I click the button, it's mac address added to allowed device list of my WiFi hotspot. How to do that using android programming? Any code, android library or advice.